# Focal length of the sony DSC-H20

Tags: focal-length, sony, distortion, focus-distance

I am working in finding the distance of the objects in a video taken using a Sony Camera model DSC-H20 and suppose that any lens or zoom distortions were applied.

In order to know the position I need to know a priori the real size of the object,   the size in the picture and some other data including the focal length of my camera. Does any one know what is the focal length of the Sony DSC-H20?

Comment: I hope that you mean **distance** instead of **position**. If you are really looking for position (like real world 3d coordinates), it's gonna be a *little* harder :) As your question is really about video (or about how to get a focal length from a video), you should post it to video.stackexchange.com. I have deleted my answer, which was about still picture and distance computing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because calculating distance to objects is using a camera as a different type of instrument (a digital tape measure?) rather than about photography.

Comment: I agree mattdm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, the [DSC-H20](http://www.dpreview.com/products/sony/compacts/sony_dsch20/specifications) is a zoom camera with a focal length that varies from 6.3 to 63 mm (or 38 to 380 mm if you're using to thinking in terms of 35 mm film). Unless you've got the EXIF data for the images you're looking at, I suspect you're probably stuck here.